# Passing router value as prop

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm passing the data as

route

```js
{
    path: '/name/:nameSlug',
    name: 'NameItem',
    props: true,
    components: { home: Name }
},
```

router link to component

```html
<router-link :to="{ name: 'NameItem', params: { nameSlug: name.nameSlug } }">
  {{ name.english }} 
</router-link>
 // name object
{
  "id": 1303,
  "english": "bob",
  "gender": "M",
  "nameSlug": "bob"
}
```

NameItem props

```js
props: {
    nameSlug: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
},
```

I'm getting the following error for this page, what is the issue? using "vue-router": "^3.2.0":

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'nameSlug' of undefined

or this, note the url does change correctly

> [Vue warn]: Missing required prop: "nameSlug"

[image]

Comment: What line of code and in what file is causing that error?

Comment: Looks more like the issue is with `name.nameSlug` than anything to do with the router or props. What does `name` object look like?

Comment: @Phil the NameItem component,so /name/bob

Comment: @raklos that doesn't answer my question at all. When you see that error (presumably in your browser console), it will include a file and line number. You can even click through to it to see the source. What does that line of code look like?

Comment: @Phil I have updated, similar issue here, but not sure if if he got it working https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vue-router-2-2-0-not-seeing-params-in-props/5904/5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this note in the [documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#passing-props-to-route-components)...

> for routes with named views, you have to define the `props` option for each named view

Your route uses the named view "home" so you will need something like the following

```js
{
  path: '/name/:nameSlug',
  name: 'NameItem',
  props: {
    default: true,
    home: true
  },
  components: { home: Name }
},
```